# How to add new layer to my own android maps application with KML

Tags: android, google-maps, kml

I wrote application which just shows Google Maps and now need to add layer with markers. I will be very grateful if someone could tell me how to import layer from KML file ?

Comment: Show us what you have done or researched so far. Also please read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

I abandoned attempt to add layer from KML so I'll try to add overlays from this tutorial http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html